# Getting NoClassDefFound error while using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am pretty new to spring and I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedIOException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:323)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at demo.SpringDemoApplication.main(SpringDemoApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 8 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I created all classes and I don't think there is a problem with it. I think there is a problem with configuration or dependencies (not sure). I know this is very basic error so please bear with me. I attach all my code here

```
package demo;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Doctor implements Staff{
    
    public void assist() {
        System.out.println("He helps");
    }
}
```

```
package demo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "demo")
public class BeanConfig {

}
```

```
package demo;

import demo.Doctor;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

//@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);
        Doctor doctor = context.getBean(Doctor.class);
        doctor.assist();
//      System.out.println("injection" + doctor.getInjection() );
//      SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>springDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The thing is this thing worked for xml config but not for annotation. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: From the documentation for class [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html): _The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found._ In other words, the problem is in your runtime CLASSPATH (or module path).

Comment: But I don't see how the definition just vanished. Is that a spring stuff I gotta learn? Also can you help me how to fix the code above

Comment: Remove the `spring-context` dependency, that is from an older Spring version and incompatible. Next to that it isn't needed as the starter dependencies already pull in the `spring-context` dependency.

Comment: Thanks soo much guys it helped. I am new so the very basic doubts. :)